# Совпадающие элементы в массиве

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, pascal

Здравствуйте. В колледже весь курс проходили паскаль и настало время практики. Дали индивидуальные задания и сроки. Не скажу, что паскалем владею в совершенстве, скорее на уровне опытного пользователя. В задании было всего 5 задач, 4 из которых успешно выполнены и записаны в отчёт, а вот с пятой возникли трудности.

Текст задачи:

> Дан двумерный массив положительных целых чисел. Известно, что в нём присутствуют совпадающие элементы (одинаковые числа). Вывести их индексы.

Всё вроде бы и звучит просто и не должно занимать много времени, но придумать алгоритм не могу. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Алгоритм поиска то мне был понятен и до того как и я выводил индексы, проблема была в дублировании. Нормального решения так и не нашёл, придумал индийский метод с заменой числа на другое после вывода его индексов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 берем первый элемент проверяем с остальными

2 если попадается одинаковый - выводим индекс копии и индекс проверяемого элемента

3 крутимся в цикле пока есть елементы в массиве

Хорошо бы ввести проверку типа, если индекс копии меньше индекса проверяемого элемента - нечего не делать, так как он уже будет учтен

Comment: Решение самое-самое банальное...можно было бы, например, прикрутить сюда алгоритм поиска одинаковых элементов, основанный на алгоритме, используемом в быстрой сортировке.

Comment: Конечно, просто вопрос задавал гуру паскаля, потому сильно замарачиватся там не стоит я думаю....

Comment: 2 @Asen: не стоит придумывать велосипед, намного эффективнее было бы сначала отсортировать массив той же быстрой сортировкой. После сортировки делаем еще один проход для того чтоб вывести индексы одинаковых элеметов: если текущий элемент равен предыдущему выводим индексы. Если обязательно выводить индексы элементов только по 1му разу, то придется добавить еще один внутренний цикл для этого. результат: приличная скорость + понятный алгоритм

Answer (score 2):

Создаём массив индексов, т.е. заполняем массив натуральным рядом. Берём первый элемент, сравниваем с остальными в цикле. Индексы меньших записываем в один массив, больших - в другой (или с конца или сначала к середине нового массива), индексы равных выводим. Повторяем рекурсивно то же для меньших и для больших пока длина больше 1.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный алгоритм требует каждый раз пробегаться по всем элементам для сравнения. 
Можно сделать еще трехмерный массив где будут сохраняться значения вида (число, индекс в первоначальном массиве) и отсортировать по возрастанию.
Получится чтото типа 10, 19, 89, 128, 170, 230, 300, ...
Далее берем число1 из первого массива и сравниваем. Если число1 становится меньше числа из второго массива то break

экономим N/2 пробежек на каждом проходе